# Does Spring AuthenticationManager keep valid tokens somewhere in memory?

Tags: java, spring

Does Spring AuthenticationManager keep valid tokens somewhere in memory ?

or should we keep the valid tokens in a table/db somewhere? Is this already implemented in Spring security ?

This is the login filter for my Spring boot application :

```
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {


    public JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException,
            IOException, ServletException {

        CustomUserDetails creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
                req.getInputStream(), CustomUserDetails.class);

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) {
        TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
    }
}
```